# Why does PHP child process become zombie?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, zombie-process

I have a script that does several tasks.
In order to avoid timeout, memorylimits, crossvar and so on I decided to have a main script that fork all the taks on different PHP process.

I can run manually the script and work fine.

I can run manually every single child process and work fine.

However from time to time I see that some of child process are running forever and I have to kill them from top.

Does anybody know why a PHP process executed by CLI should become zombie and avoiding to close itself and also the main process?

**The Spawn process:**

```
foreach ($OPS as $OP) {
    $command = $PHP_BIN." ".__DIR__."/process_this.php op_id=".$OP["id"];
    exec($command);
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: "running forever" and "becomes a zombie" are completely different things. Chances are you have a bug somewhere that causes the process to hang or loop indefinitely.

Comment: Yeas, but since any of these child process have an infinite loop...
They also have a clear PHP timeout... 
So they are running forever because they become zombie

Comment: How do you spawn the children, show code.

Comment: A zombie process is a process that terminated after its parent process has been terminated and therefore no one was around to clean it up.

Comment: I have updated the  question with the spawn process

Comment: For example if you kill the Spawn process while a child is running that child process will become a zombie once it terminates.

Comment: All those process are terminated... for sure.
The fact is that they seems to be.... completed but not cleaned.

Comment: Ok so if the real sequence is the following: `CRON` -> fork to `PHP` -> fork to `child process`, then is it possible that the CRON have been killed and so I just see main PHP process and some of the childrens?

Comment: if the cron process is killed while waiting for the parent process then the parent process would become a zombie once it finishes. however the cron process is usually very robust so the fact that it terminated is probably an indication that something in the child processes caused it to die by e.g. running out of memory or other resources.

Comment: If a PHP process run out of memory, it just die in the shell and in apache.
Why should become zombie in a cli environment?